# Bootstrap-table filterBy method doesn't work?

Tags: bootstrap-table

I use the filterBy method like this:

$(`#${this.tbId}`).bootstrapTable('filterBy', { total: 1,rows:this.allData})

but it doesn't work,why?

Comment: We're going to need to see more of the code to find out why it's not working for you. Maybe a JSFiddle as well?

Comment: Do you mean `load` method?